# PC boots on BIOS but gets blurred AFTER

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard

Hello I have a very odd problem in my Computer. It runs properly. But there are times when I boot it this happens.

- Turns on (fans running and etc)
- Shows the BIOS
- The display then gets blurred and turns off after a few seconds.
- After a few restart windows recovery screen will appear. (Only tried startup repair. Message said windows cant repair)
- Restarting again and finally reached desktop.

[image: BIOS image] -
[image: Blurred Screen image]

[image: windows recovery]

I just bought my GPU and installed it properly including drivers. This problem didn't happen before when I was using my integrated graphics. I am using HDMI cable.

Any solutions for this problem? Thanks

Windows 10. My specs

- Ryzen 3 3200g
- Biostar b450m motherboard
- 400w psu
- Biostar rx 560 4gb dual fan(No 6 pin needed)

**EDIT: GPU History**

When I first bought this GPU i tried installing it on my pc and it didn't work even after many restarts only bios and blurred screen appears and then shuts down and it wont even reach the recovery screen so I thought it was broken. Then I tried it on my friends PC and the GPU works fine so I thought this was a cable problem and then I bought a new HDMI cable (the HDMI cable I used previously was from our TV and i think its not compatible with my monitor). Tried the new cable and then it works fine. Installed drivers then played games I get higher fps than before. Then the problem above occurred: *there are times when I boot the PC this happens.*

Comment: This is an indication your GPU is not functional.  Did you purchase this GPU new or used?  Specifications for the card indicated the minimum PSU is 500 W.  Were you aware of that fact?

Comment: Hey thanks for checking out my question. This GPU is new. It worked on my friends pc (he has 250W PSU). This website also says that suggested PSU is 250 W. https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/biostar-rx-560-dual-cooling.b4796 .Yes I am aware that GPU needs power requirements so I checked before buying it. I will also add something in my question that might help.

Comment: If this problem happens when you boot the PC, the problem is the GPU, more than likely PSU problem.  When I looked up the specifications for the card you purchased, the documentation I found, indicates 450 W PSU is required.

Comment: Okay thanks for the information. I am also planning on buying a new PSU if this problem will happen more frequently. I also have tight budget atm. Thanks a lot